# How to import a secondary module to use a function which requires updated global variables from the first executing module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a module A which imports a module B. Module A has global variables that are constantly changing. The function I need to run from module B needs the updated value of these variables. I am trying something like this:

Module A.py:

```
test_var = 0

def updateA():
    import B
    B.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for _ in range(100):
        updateA()
        print(test_var)
```

Module B.py:

```
import A
def update():
    A.test_var += 1
```

Which should print numbers from 0 to 00.
This is just simplified example of what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of directly referencing variables in Module A. Pass the variable as a parameter to the update function.

For example in Module A.py:

```
test_var = 0

def updateA():
    global test_var // Ensure usage of global scope
    test_var = test_var + 1
    import B
    B.update(test_var)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for _ in range(100):
        updateA()
    print(test_var)
```

And in Module B.py

```
def update(var)
    print(var)
```

Comment: H. Ross thank you for your reply. However, when module B.py gets imported, it will import a new module A, which is not the same instance that was originally running, wouldn't this cause A.getVar() return the initial value of test_var, instead of the updated one?

Comment: You are correct, thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my answer to a better solution.

Comment: Thank you H. Ross. Now to make it a little more complicated, I happen to have a thread that is constantly running when I execute the function in module B, this thread needs to read test_var and also change it. I am beginning to think there is no way of doing this, and I think I should move my functions from the B module to the A (I wanted to have them more organized in different files as they have very different purposes in my program), however if you can think of a way to do this might be very helpful.

Comment: It may be very difficult or impossible to do so: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982753/global-variables-accross-modules-and-threads-in-python

Comment: Understood, thank you so much for your help. I'll move everything to the same file then.